# Does elementary OS work inside Hyper-V?

Tags: system-installation, microsoft-windows, virtualization

I have a problem regarding installation elementary OS on virtual machine using Hyper-V[image]

I am green at using Linux, it is supposed to be my linux distro exclusively for Ruby(on Rails) development. I suppose it could be that elementary is BIOS based and Windows 10 is UEFI based. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can work with gen 2. Before starting VM go into settings -> security. Disable secure boot and save it. Start your VM and go install.

Answer (score 3):

Linux did not work in Hyper V for UEFI installations until very recently. You should find that elementary OS Freya works with legacy mode enabled, or that Loki works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the VM you will be asked to pick the Generation.

- **Generation 1** will work perfectly.
- **Generation 2** will work IF after you have created the VM using the wizard, you go into the settings of the virtual machine. Change the Security for **Microsoft UEFI Certificate Authority**

However, you will be limited to a screen resolution under 1920×1080. If it's not a problem for you then great! If you would like a bigger resolution you will need to install [XRDP](http://www.xrdp.org/).

> with elementary OS 5 Juno

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only with Generation 1 VMs, configurable at the time of VM creation. There is no sound, and no video acceleration will mean the system will be sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

Бред. Всё прекрасно ставится. Нужно только отключить "Безопасную загрузку"

[image]

Comment: Could you translate your answer? You might want to recapture screenshots as well running the hypervisor with `LOCALE=C`

Comment: Google Translation, `... Everything is fine set. It is only necessary to disable the "Safe Download"` but screenshot is still in Russian. @mapazzzm thanks for trying to share your knowledge with the community.

Answer (score -1):

[image: ![enter image description here]

hyper-v quick create do well..